# Error with truffle deploy command

Tags: truffle, consensys-truffle

I want to deploy a smart contract to a private network.

I start the network like this

> geth --datadir="~/truffle" --port 30303 --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr
> localhost --networkid 27441 --rpccorsdomain="*" --minerthreads "1"
> --mine --rpcapi "eth,web3" --maxpeers 4 --unlock=0

then I run ’truffle deploy'
I get the message:

> Error deploying SimpleStorage:
>
> Account does not exist or account balance too low Deploy failed.
>
> See above."

Could you please give me some ideas about this?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure:
1. You are typing password after starting geth, to unlock your account.
2. You have enough ether in your selected account.